# Heat death of universe, are there any interactions

Tags: cosmology, universe

As far as I understand, in the so called "Heat death of universe" universe is still expanding, but in that case, average distance among particles is gradually increasing to infinity, and likelihood (and rate) of any particle interaction therefore must decrease to zero. If this is not the case, how particles can interact on such gigantic distances, or is there anything preventing them to get infinitely distant from each other?

Answer (score 1):

Well a nice version of the heat death is given by Penrose with the CCC theory. The universe is expanding and aging... Here aging means everything decays. The last decay product is supposed to be photons, and after the last black hole evaporated there are only photons filling the universe. As photons are massless, there are only massless particles, thus you cannot define distances nor time, as there are no clocks at your disposal.

This leads to the compactification of infinities to a point, which suddenly squeeses the whole universe (as no distances, the biggest distance is also equivalent with the shortest distance) and you get a new bigbang. A cycle is called :eon, and all the eons create a conformal cyclic cosmology.

There is a caveat, however, as gravitational waves may survive it, caused by the explosion of the evaporating black holes at the end of their times. These gravitational waves will be wavefront in the new eon after the conformal transformation and new big bang, and they should be visible on the CMB radiation as circles.

Penrose claims that he sees those circles, however, there is a heated debate.

I don't like infinite cyclic Universes but Penrose's model is well-explained and testable.

EDIT:

i'm answering the comment here because it was too long:

This is a hypothesis. I have for example a problem with it: the universe is expanding exponentially, thus some regions can "decouple" from each other, as they will be outside of each other's light cone. What tells region "A" that region "B" (that had the last black hole in the universe),  that it just exploded? If they are not causally connected, then the decoupled regions are practically speaking separate universes, thus the big bang in Penrose's theory should already happen in region A, and only in regions that are causally connected with the black hole from region "B" should still stay in the previous epoch. This would of course lead to universes, where part of it has a new scale, and region A is in the new eon already, scaled up, the thing in region B should become a tiny thing. Although maybe Penrose accounts for that, I'm not sure. Next time I meet him (at any conference, where I will be lucky to be present) I will definitely ask it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. RE: "there are only massless particles, thus you cannot define distances nor time", this would explain why end-particles (photons) never get infinitely far away from each other. But is this ("end of clock') only part of mentioned Penrose's theory or universaly accepted hypothesis?

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question to AI chatbot at https://chat.openai.com/chat, here is the answer:

In an expanding universe, the distances between particles will increase over time. However, it is not currently believed that the expansion of the universe will cause particles to become so distant from each other that they will no longer be able to interact. This is because the fundamental forces of nature, such as gravity and electromagnetism, have an infinite range, which means that they can act over arbitrarily large distances.

In addition, the expansion of the universe is not uniform, and the gravitational attraction between particles can cause them to cluster together and form structures such as galaxies and clusters of galaxies. This means that even as the universe continues to expand, particles will remain gravitationally bound to each other and continue to interact through the fundamental forces of nature.

Therefore, it is not expected that the expansion of the universe will cause particles to become so distant from each other that they will no longer be able to interact.